# Sending messages between CANs FD with different bitrates

Tags: can

In my team we are performing some CAN FD tests. We are trying to extend our current tests for classic CAN to cover FD and while trying to send message between CANs FD with different bit-rates we have faced a bit unexpected situation. In case of classic CAN the behavior is pretty obvious (different bit-rates - no message sent or received), but for CAN FD it's not that simple. It turned out that our CANs FD can actually send and receive messages when their arbitration bit-rates are the same, but data bit-rates differ. For opposite situation, when arbitration bit-rates differ and data bit-rates are the same then no message is being sent.

This situation occurs while performing our unit tests and when trying to send messages with linux tool - cansend.

My question is: does CAN FD protocol allow frames transfer for the same arbitration bit-rates, but different data bit-rates?

I wasn't able to find answer on my question on this forum nor in official Bosch documentation.

Comment: are you saying different CAN-FD are operating at different rates to each other. fundamentally CAN-FD increases the datarate AFTER arbitration to 5MB/s, but they should all be ~ the same

Comment: Yes, they are having different data bit-rate, but the same arbitration bit-rate and yet they are able to communicate each other.

Comment: I suspect this depends on if all CAN controllers on the network support CAN FD or not. Otherwise if they are classic CAN controllers, I would expect the network to be drowned in error frames pretty fast.